# Way to optimize this case when sql query

Tags: sql, optimization, case

```
WITH cte AS 
(   
    SELECT
        channelGrouping,
        visitnumber AS times,
        COUNT(*) AS number_of_visitor   
    FROM
        `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*`   
    WHERE
        _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'ga_sessions_20160801' AND 'ga_sessions_20171213'
        AND FullvisitorID IN (SELECT fullVisitorID
                              FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.*`
                              WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'ga_sessions_20160801'
                                                      AND 'ga_sessions_20171213'
                              GROUP BY fullvisitorID
                              HAVING COUNT(fullvisitorid) > 1)    
    GROUP BY
        channelgrouping,
        visitnumber   
    ORDER BY
        channelgrouping,
        times
) 
SELECT   
    *,   
    (number_of_visitor * 100 /
        (CASE
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Organic Search' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor 
                       FROM cte 
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping = 'Organic Search')
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Social' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor
                       FROM cte
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping = 'Social')
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Direct' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor 
                       FROM cte 
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping
='Direct')
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Referral' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor
                       FROM cte
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping = 'Referral')
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Paid Search' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor 
                       FROM cte 
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping ='Paid Search')
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Affiliates' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor
                       FROM cte
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping = 'Affiliates')
             WHEN channelgrouping = 'Display' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor 
                       FROM cte 
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping = 'Display')
             WHEN channelgrouping = '(Other)' 
                 THEN (SELECT number_of_visitor
                       FROM cte
                       WHERE times = 1 AND channelgrouping = '(Other)')
         END)) AS retention_rate 
FROM   
    cte 
WHERE   
    times > 1 
ORDER BY   
    cte.channelgrouping, cte.times
```

There are only 8 `channelgrouping`, so I can list them. Just wonder if there is a better way to reduce the repetition? What if there are 100 `channelgroupings`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including some demo data and expected results. Better yet, as described under [Help others reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) add this query and example data to https://www.db-fiddle.com/ so we can run the query directly.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to repeat the same query multiple times in the `CASE` statement. In fact, there doesn't appear to be any need for a `CASE` statement at all, since the inner query can reference the outer query and you say these are the only possible values.

You should be able to do something more like:

```
WITH cte AS (
...
)
SELECT *, 
 number_of_visitor * 100 /
 (
  SELECT number_of_visitor
  FROM cte cte2
  WHERE cte2.times = 1 AND cte1.channelgrouping = cte2.channelgrouping
 )
FROM cte cte1
WHERE   
    times > 1 
ORDER BY   
    cte1.channelgrouping, cte1.times
```

I should note that this reduces the repetition in the existing query which I think is the intention of your question. I'm clarifying since "optimize" when talking about queries usually has a performance connotation. What I'm suggesting will make the query easier to read and easier to maintain ("What if there are 100 `channelgroupings`"), but won't necessarily improve performance.